# ExecutorService.invokeAll vs Future.get for each result -- difference

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

Not suitable title sorry for that. I want to   wait until  status of all `thread` result. I can do this using `ExecutorService.invokeAll` and calling `future.get()` // which will wait for result in for loop , if both provides the same functionality then why two different function, please tell me if any other different apart from submitting task in `collection`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They do not do the same thing. invokeall method is the one executing the tasks, and will block until all tasks have finished(either successfully or not). Upon completion of all tasks it returns a list of futures. You can then call future.get() for each of these futures to get the results (or an ExecutionException for those tasks that did not complete successfully)